# Jira - How to calculate count of days in status?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

Jira Data Center.
How to find the number of days a task was in progress?
Will explain
tostring - Status of the task it moved to
fromString - Status of the task it came from

So, I need to understand how many days the task spent in work
No need to take into account hours and minutes, just the number of days
And at the same time, only those days in which the task had the In Progress status

This is what I have

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

// Status to be counted
final statusName = 'In Progress'

def changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.changeHistoryManager
def datesInStatus = [:]

// Get all status change items
def changeItems = changeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField(issue, "status")
def previousDate = null

changeItems.findAll { it.toString == 'In Progress' || it.fromString == 'In Progress' }.each { item ->
     addMessage(item.toString())
}
```

This is the output from addMessage
`com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean@1e5b1b95[fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10614,fromString=In Progress,to=10614,toString=In Progress,created=2024-02-26 14:29 :31.846], com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean@21c854c9[fieldType=jira,field=status,from=14201,fromString=Testing,to=10614,toString=In Progress,created=2024-02-26 14:29:31.47], com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean@1b94684b[fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10614,fromString=In Progress,to=10501,toString=CODE REVIEW,created=2023 -12-13 18:02:23.731]`

Comment: That is not Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example values such as `2024-02-26 14:29:31.47` are faulty in that they lack an indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we cannot know, for example, if that was 2:29 PM in Tokyo Japan or 2:29 PM in Toledo Ohio US, two very different moments several hours apart.

If you want to pretend/assume those values are for generic 24-hour days, parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input.replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

Collect and sort. Feed the first and last into [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)) if you define “days” as 24-hour chunks of time.

```
Duration.between(
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2023 -12-13 18:02:23.731".replace( " " , "T" ) ) , 
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2024-02-26 14:29:31.846".replace( " " , "T" ) ) 
).toDays()
```

If you define “days” by the calendar, feed the pair of `LocalDateTime` objects to [`Period.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#between(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)).